# How to use HTML buttons in a Webview in and Android app?

Tags: java, android, html, eclipse, webview

I have a shell of an app written in Java(Eclipse) that just returns a Webview. In this html that the Webview returns, i have a button that should take you to the next page.

When you click the button, it just highlights orange and does nothing. If i make it a link() it will go to the next page.

In my code below, they're are two buttons generated in different ways. They both display a button on the app but do nothing when clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        Welcome to this page blah blah blah
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onClick="parent.location='fred.htm'"/>
        <button onClick="parent.location='fred.htm'">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Im not sure why it didnt cross my mind before...

But i just put a button inside my link. So i ended up with:

```
<a href="fred.htm"><button>Click Me!</button></a>
```

Not sure if that's the correct way to do it but it looks like a button and it works like a button.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the JavaScript you are executing in your onclick handler.

Try

location.href = 'fred.htm';

instead of using parent.href.